# Python Stock Screener

Tags: python, pandas

I will build a simple stock screener with python. The screener should receive the volume and avg. volume from different stocks und should list all stocks with a higher volume then the avg. volume in a simple table.

The problem is that I always get a error in the if loop with the condition.

```
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_analysts_info, get_stats, get_live_price, get_quote_table
import pandas as pd
import ssl


ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

tickers = ['aapl', 'ayx']

stocks = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ticker', 'Volume_1', 'Average_Volume'])

for ticker in tickers:
    df = get_stats(ticker)
    df['ticker'] = ticker
    df = df.pivot(index = 'ticker', columns = 'Attribute', values = 'Value')
    df['Volume_1'] = get_quote_table(ticker)['Volume']
    df['Average_Volume'] = get_quote_table(ticker)['Avg. Volume']
    df = df[['Volume_1', 'Average_Volume']]
    df = df.reset_index()
    df.columns = ('ticker', 'Volume_1', 'Average_Volume')

    stocks = stocks.append(df, ignore_index = True)

for stock in stocks:


    Volume_1 = df["Volume_1"]
    Average_Volume = df["Average_Volume"]


    if float(Volume_1) > float(Average_Volume):

            exportList = stocks.append({'Volume_1': Volume_1, "Average_Volume": Avgerage_Volume},
                                           ignore_index=True)

df["Volume_1"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Volume_1"], downcast="float")
exportList = stock.sort_values(by='Volume_1', ascending=False)
print('\n', exportList)
```

Comment: *What* error? Give a [mre].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try converting the Volume and Avg Volume to floats, they might be strings.

```
if float(Volume_1) > float(Average_Volume):
    #do your processing here
```

If this does not work, post the error you get and I'll try to assist you further.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your fast answer! This seems to work, but now i get a other error.. it seems that i have more problems with the code.. 

line 36, in <module>
    exportList = stock.sort_values(by='Volume', ascending=False)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Comment: Same error, the volume is a str. Try adding this line before exportList:
`df["Volume"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Volume"], downcast="float")`

Comment: now i get this error :( 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Volume'

Comment: `df["Volume_1"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Volume_1"], downcast="float")`

Comment: thats confusing for me.. : line 37, in <module>
    exportList = stock.sort_values(by='Volume_1', ascending=False)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

I updated the code in the post

Comment: i have it :) Problem was that i named it export list and not stocks...Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Great. Accept my answer if it helped. :)